# joomla - how can I create new content types in joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm new to joomla. I have been using Drupal for quite some time.

I would like to created new content types for news and announcements. How may I accomplish creating new content type in Joomla without installing a new module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're coming from Drupal so I am thinking that what you're looking for and cannot find in Joomla is something like CCK (Content Construction Kit)

Unfortunately this is not available by default in Joomla. You have to use extensions to create new types of content that contain specific fields.

Best free CCKs available for Joomla :

1. [Form2Content](http://www.form2content.com/) (my favorite)
2. [K2](http://getk2.org/) (most popular, highly recommended)

You can find more in [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction)

Comment: Not available **yet**!

Answer (score 0):

I would say the same, for me i always use k2 as it integrates with many plugins and modules also featuring rich content forms

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer from @Ahmad, install a [CCK](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/authoring-a-content/content-construction) to add new content types.

In your case however, the built in Joomla functionality may suffice such as creating content categories for news and announcements and choosing menu options or modules to suit.

Answer (score 0):

While K2 is a great CCK, there is a table named "jos_content_types", which makes me think, that joomla can handle content-types as well.
With different views, form-xml files and so one.

I found it while looking on this page: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension

But i didn't find any doc about creating new content-types easily by now. Does someone have more infos, how to create a new content-Type? Or is it just a new component, we have to create?